# Keep music player playing when app is closed with exoplayer

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, media, exoplayer

I have a music app built with exoplayer.

I want to:

**Keep the song playing even when the app is closed.**

**I also want to add a close (X) icon to the notification tray (If possible, so user can close the media session from there)**

Right now, when I close the app. Song stops playing.

**MusicService**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MusicService : MediaBrowserServiceCompat() {

@Inject
lateinit var dataSourceFactory: DefaultDataSourceFactory

@Inject
lateinit var exoPlayer: SimpleExoPlayer

@Inject
lateinit var musicSource: MusicSource

private lateinit var musicNotificationManager: MusicNotificationManager

private val serviceJob = Job()
private val serviceScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + serviceJob)

private lateinit var mediaSession: MediaSessionCompat
private lateinit var mediaSessionConnector: MediaSessionConnector

var isForegroundService = false

private var currPlayingSong: MediaMetadataCompat? = null

private var isPlayerInitialized = false


private lateinit var musicPlayerEventListener: MusicPlayerEventListener

companion object {
    var curSongDuration = 0L
        private set
}


override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    serviceScope.launch {
        musicSource.fetchMediaData()
    }


    val activityIntent = packageManager?.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)?.let {
        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, it, 0)
    }

    mediaSession = MediaSessionCompat(this, SERVICE_TAG).apply {
        setSessionActivity(activityIntent)
        isActive = true
    }

    sessionToken = mediaSession.sessionToken

    musicNotificationManager = MusicNotificationManager(
        this,
        mediaSession.sessionToken,
        MusicPlayerNotificationListener(this)
    ) {
        curSongDuration = exoPlayer.duration
    }

    val musicPlayBackPreparer = MusicPlaybackPreparer(musicSource) {
        currPlayingSong = it
        preparePlayer(
            musicSource.songs,
            it,
            true
        )
    }

    mediaSessionConnector = MediaSessionConnector(mediaSession)
    mediaSessionConnector.setPlaybackPreparer(musicPlayBackPreparer)
    mediaSessionConnector.setQueueNavigator(MusicQueueNavigator())
    mediaSessionConnector.setPlayer(exoPlayer)

    musicPlayerEventListener = MusicPlayerEventListener(this)
    exoPlayer.addListener(musicPlayerEventListener)
    musicNotificationManager.showNotification(exoPlayer)

}


private inner class MusicQueueNavigator : TimelineQueueNavigator(mediaSession) {
    override fun getMediaDescription(player: Player, windowIndex: Int): MediaDescriptionCompat {
        return musicSource.songs[windowIndex].description
    }
}

private fun preparePlayer(
    songs: List<MediaMetadataCompat>,
    itemToPlay: MediaMetadataCompat?,
    playNow: Boolean
) {

    val curSongIndex = if (currPlayingSong == null) 0 else songs.indexOf(itemToPlay)
    exoPlayer.prepare(musicSource.asMediaSource(dataSourceFactory))
    exoPlayer.seekTo(curSongIndex, 0L)
    exoPlayer.playWhenReady = playNow

}

override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
    exoPlayer.stop()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    serviceScope.cancel()

    exoPlayer.removeListener(musicPlayerEventListener)
    exoPlayer.release()

}

override fun onGetRoot(
    clientPackageName: String,
    clientUid: Int,
    rootHints: Bundle?
): BrowserRoot {
    return BrowserRoot(MEDIA_ROOT_ID, null)
}

override fun onLoadChildren(
    parentId: String,
    result: Result<MutableList<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>>
) {
    when (parentId) {
        MEDIA_ROOT_ID -> {
            val resultsSent = musicSource.whenReady { isInitialized ->
                if (isInitialized) {
                    result.sendResult(musicSource.asMediaItem())
                    if (!isInitialized && musicSource.songs.isNotEmpty()) {
                        preparePlayer(musicSource.songs, musicSource.songs[0], false)
                        isPlayerInitialized = true
                    }
                } else {
                    mediaSession.sendSessionEvent(NETWORK_ERROR, null)
                    result.sendResult(null)
                }
            }
            if (!resultsSent) {
                result.detach()
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

**MusicServiceConnection**

```
class MusicServiceConnection(context: Context) {

private val _isConnected = MutableLiveData<Event<Resource<Boolean>>>()
val isConnected: LiveData<Event<Resource<Boolean>>> = _isConnected

private val _networkError = MutableLiveData<Event<Resource<Boolean>>>()
val networkError: LiveData<Event<Resource<Boolean>>> = _networkError

private val _playbackState = MutableLiveData<PlaybackStateCompat?>()
val playbackState: LiveData<PlaybackStateCompat?> = _playbackState

private val _currentPlayingSong = MutableLiveData<MediaMetadataCompat?>()
val currentPlayingSong: LiveData<MediaMetadataCompat?> = _currentPlayingSong

lateinit var mediaControllerCompat: MediaControllerCompat

private val mediaBrowserControllerCallback = MediaBrowserConnectionCallback(context)

private val mediaBrowser = MediaBrowserCompat(
    context,
    ComponentName(
        context,
        MusicService::class.java
    ),
    mediaBrowserControllerCallback,
    null
).apply { connect() }

val transportControls : MediaControllerCompat.TransportControls
get() = mediaControllerCompat.transportControls

fun subscribe(parentId: String, callback: MediaBrowserCompat.SubscriptionCallback){
    mediaBrowser.subscribe(parentId, callback)
}

fun unSubscribe(parentId: String, callback: MediaBrowserCompat.SubscriptionCallback){
    mediaBrowser.unsubscribe(parentId, callback)
}


private inner class MediaBrowserConnectionCallback(
    private val context: Context
): MediaBrowserCompat.ConnectionCallback(){

    override fun onConnected() {
        mediaControllerCompat = MediaControllerCompat(context, mediaBrowser.sessionToken).apply {
            registerCallback(MediaControllerCallback())
        }
        _isConnected.postValue(Event(Resource.success(true)))
    }

    override fun onConnectionSuspended() {
        _isConnected.postValue(Event(Resource.error("Data was suspended", false)))
    }

    override fun onConnectionFailed() {
        _isConnected.postValue(Event(Resource.error("couldn't connect", false)))
    }
}

private inner class MediaControllerCallback: MediaControllerCompat.Callback(){

    override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(state: PlaybackStateCompat?) {
        _playbackState.postValue(state)
    }

    override fun onMetadataChanged(metadata: MediaMetadataCompat?) {
        _currentPlayingSong.postValue(metadata)
    }

    override fun onSessionEvent(event: String?, extras: Bundle?) {
        super.onSessionEvent(event, extras)
        when(event){

            NETWORK_ERROR -> _networkError.postValue(
                Event(
                    Resource.error(
                        "Something went wrong",
                        null
                    )
                )
            )

        }
    }


    override fun onSessionDestroyed() {
        mediaBrowserControllerCallback.onConnectionSuspended()
    }
  }
}
```

**MusicNotificationManager**

```
class MusicNotificationManager(
private val context: Context,
sessionToken: MediaSessionCompat.Token,
notificationListener: PlayerNotificationManager.NotificationListener,
private val newSongCallback: () -> Unit
) {
private val notificationManager: PlayerNotificationManager
init {
    val mediaController = MediaControllerCompat(context, sessionToken)
    notificationManager = PlayerNotificationManager.createWithNotificationChannel(
        context,
        NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
        R.string.notification_channel_name,
        R.string.notification_channel_description,
        NOTIFICATION_ID,
        DescriptionAdapter(mediaController),
        notificationListener
    ).apply {

        setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo_svg)
        setMediaSessionToken(sessionToken)
        setRewindIncrementMs(0)
        setUseNavigationActionsInCompactView(true)
        setFastForwardIncrementMs(0)
        setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)

    }

}

fun showNotification(player: Player) {
    notificationManager.setPlayer(player)
}

private inner class DescriptionAdapter(
    private val mediaController: MediaControllerCompat
) : PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter {

    override fun getCurrentContentTitle(player: Player): CharSequence {
        newSongCallback()
        return mediaController.metadata.description.title.toString()
    }

    override fun createCurrentContentIntent(player: Player): PendingIntent? {
        return mediaController.sessionActivity
    }

    override fun getCurrentContentText(player: Player): CharSequence {
        return mediaController.metadata.description.subtitle.toString()
    }

    override fun getCurrentLargeIcon(
        player: Player,
        callback: PlayerNotificationManager.BitmapCallback
    ): Bitmap? {


        Glide.with(context).asBitmap()
            .load(mediaController.metadata.description.iconUri)
            .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {

                override fun onResourceReady(
                    resource: Bitmap,
                    transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?
                ) {
                    callback.onBitmap(resource)
                }

                override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) = Unit

            })
        return null
    }
 }
}
```

**MusicPlayerNotificationListener**

```
class MusicPlayerNotificationListener(
private val musicService: MusicService
) : PlayerNotificationManager.NotificationListener {

override fun onNotificationCancelled(notificationId: Int, dismissedByUser: Boolean) {
    super.onNotificationCancelled(notificationId, dismissedByUser)
    musicService.apply {
        stopForeground(true)
        isForegroundService = false
        stopSelf()
    }
}

override fun onNotificationPosted(
    notificationId: Int,
    notification: Notification,
    ongoing: Boolean
) {
    super.onNotificationPosted(notificationId, notification, ongoing)
    musicService.apply {
        if(ongoing && !isForegroundService){
            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this,
            Intent(applicationContext, this::class.java)
                )
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
            isForegroundService = true
        }
    }
 }
}
```

**MusicPlayerEventListener**

```
class MusicPlayerEventListener(
private val musicService: MusicService): Player.EventListener {
override fun onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady: Boolean, playbackState: Int) {
    super.onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady, playbackState)
    if (playbackState == Player.STATE_READY && !playWhenReady){
        musicService.stopForeground(false)
    }
}

override fun onPlayerError(error: ExoPlaybackException) {
    super.onPlayerError(error)
    Toast.makeText(musicService, "An unknown error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
 }
}
```

**MusicPlayBackPreparer**

```
class MusicPlaybackPreparer(
private val musicSource: MusicSource,
private val playerPreparer: (MediaMetadataCompat?) -> Unit) : 
MediaSessionConnector.PlaybackPreparer {
override fun onCommand(
    player: Player,
    controlDispatcher: ControlDispatcher,
    command: String,
    extras: Bundle?,
    cb: ResultReceiver?
) = false

override fun getSupportedPrepareActions(): Long {
    return PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PREPARE_FROM_MEDIA_ID or
    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_FROM_MEDIA_ID
}

override fun onPrepare(playWhenReady: Boolean) = Unit

override fun onPrepareFromMediaId(mediaId: String, playWhenReady: Boolean, extras: Bundle?) {
    musicSource.whenReady {
        val itemToPlay = musicSource.songs.find {
            mediaId == it.description.mediaId
        }
        playerPreparer(itemToPlay)
    }
}

override fun onPrepareFromSearch(query: String, playWhenReady: Boolean, extras: Bundle?) = Unit

override fun onPrepareFromUri(uri: Uri, playWhenReady: Boolean, extras: Bundle?) = Unit
}
```

I have added all possible code for my current issue.

What can I do to:

1. Prevent media from stopping when the app is closed.
2. Add a close (X) icon to notification tray..On Click should stop media playing and close the notification.

Comment: Did you found any solution to solve this ? i tried to remove exoPlayer.stop() it didn't work

Answer (score -1):

Remove `exoPlayer.stop()` form  `fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?)` inside your `MusicService` class. this makes your player continue to play after you close the application.